# vcs warnings that indicate if generate blocks have a name

Tags: verilog

I need a way to find out if there are generate blocks with no instance name anywhere in a set of verilog files. I was wondering if I can compile with vcs and see warnings that indicate that there are some blocks like that. an example of a "bad" block is:

```
generate
  for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1) begin 
       ….
 end
endgenerate
```

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think VCS can do this(at least in the past it couldn't) but if you have Design Compiler or Conformal it should be possible to determine this since both will add a deterministic name to the generate scope during design elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is outside the scope of what vcs in intended for. The easier solution would be to synthesize and grep for the default name generate block instance.

You could also write a script the scans the RTL and check every `for` and `if-else` in a `generate` block has a `begin : [name]`.

If checking the RTL from the simulator is what is really needed, then you will need to write a custom VPI callback with `cbEndOfCompile`. In the callback, find and scan through all the generated statements, then check check the naming.